# How to use the .d.ts typings locally for vscode intellisense in a node.js project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I am setting up a node.js project that uses a native add-on. The native add-on includes a large number of exported functions. I've setup a typings file (`.d.ts`) that includes all the function definitions and data etc. that are exported from the native add-on. When I pack all of this up with npm, and install it into the client project, the vscode intellisense picks up all the types and all is well.

When I try to use the typings for a `test.js` in the same project as the native add-on, the typings are not being picked up, specifically the exported variables; I suspect it has something to do with the way they are exported in the `.d.ts`, or the naming of the module in the `.d.ts`.

In the `.d.ts`, I have the exports listed as;

```
interface MyI {
    Initiate() : void;
}

module 'modulename' {
    export var i : MyI;
}
```

I `require` the module in the client as (`.js` file);

```
var i = require("modulename");
```

In the test code, I require it as (since I stub it through a `index.js` file);

```
var i = require("./index.js");
```

The `index.js` in turn looks like;

```
var i = require("./lib/nativeaddon");

module.exports.i = i;
```

How to I get vscode to use the typings, locally, for the intellisense when I use the add-on (via the `index.js`) for the `test.js`?

Comment: Have you looked over setting up VS Code for typescript?  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript

Comment: I think you mean `test.ts`, not `test.js` since the javascript would not have any TS-aware intellisense. And you wouldn't see anything unless you have an `index.d.ts` file defined. If you changed to `index.ts`, things would be different, though.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg. I do mean test.js, vscode uses typescript typings to fuel their intellisense. However, naming the typings `index.d.ts` solves the intellisense issue, thanks (I previously named it after the package name). Do you have a reference for that? I'm still getting to grips with the typescript stuff and that solution didn't occur to me. Would be able to write it up as an answer?

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that about VS code. I don't use it. I only use sublime text and this is how it would work there. Sublime text would not use TS intellisense in js files AFAIK. I'll write something up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create the typings for vscode intellisense to work for both the "local" case (functional with `test.js`) and the "global" case (as a node_module), naming the file after the main/entry `.js` does the trick. In this case the `"main"` file is `index.js`, so the typings become `index.d.ts`.

This does seem natural, but I haven't been able to find the documentation for the vscode intellisense that specifies this as such.

I had previously named the typings after the package/node_module name, `packagename.d.js`) and kept the `"main"` (from `package.json`) as `index.js`. The "typings" value in the `package.json` should also match the `.d.ts` file name.

I suppose a neat alternative to the "index.js" or "main.js", would be to name the main entry point, and the corresponding typings, after the package name.

Comment: Hi, would you be able to share a minimal reproducible example? I am having trouble convincing VSCode to accept the typings as you describe them here. It seems like it should work, but I may be missing some crucial trick.

Comment: @Yawar. I don't have one immediately available, I'll look to put it together, but given the time of year, I'm not sure when I will be able to post it. If you suspect it is the native module complicating things, leave that out until you have just a intellisense working, and then fold the native module in afterwards.

Comment: Hi, sorry, forgot to update you: according to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14342 this (using in-project typings to typecheck in VSCode) is actually not possible.